# Kubernetes consumes more memory, why?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have been working with docker to run my scripts on chrome-node and firefox -node and debug with the selenium-hub image where it runs smoothly, but when I use the same with k8s the whole system slows down. Why is this happening, any idea. I am using minikubes for kubernetes and docker toolbox and docker compose for docker.

Thanks,

Comment: are you using virtualbox to run minikube?
Sometime older virtualbox causes these kind of problem

Comment: Yes I am using virtual box

Comment: Could there be other reasons behind slowing down of system

Comment: Can you tell which version of virtualbox?

Comment: Version 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: Few days back, I was experiencing same problem. Upgrading virtualbox done the trick. I was using 4.2, then upgrade to 5.2

Comment: How have you verified kubernetes is using more memory? What slows down?

Comment: kubernetes is known to require quite some resources by itself, so just having kubernetes running could already take up to 50% CPU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would definitely be an additional overhead when you start Kubernetes using minikube locally, compared to just starting a Docker container on the host.

In order to have a Kubernetes cluster, minikube creates a VM on the machine where the Kubernetes components will run in addition to the Docker container.

Anyway, minikube is not a production way for running Kubernetes. It is mostly meant for local development and testing. Therefore, you shouldn't evaluated kubernetes performance based on a minikube installation.

Comment: But even Docker when used with Docker Toolbox is running the same containers , it does not lead to any slowness while the k8s is slowing down the whole system.

Comment: @adityarawat There are many more components running on the VM created by kubernetes. You have the api server, cluster store, control manager, schedueler, docker engine ... In windows docker case, there is only a VM running a docker engine.

Comment: Also, there are many more PODs and containers running even when you start a single container. Try to ssh into the VM and check the containers running. `minkube ssh` followed by `docker ps`

Comment: Yes , I can see around 17 containers